# Quotation and reference requested

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for a quotation I once read, and I think it was by a famous mathematician. It is in the context of the balance between reading and writing mathematics, and said something like "I enjoy reading so much that I hardly have the time to write something up myself". Does anyone have an idea which quotation I might mean and who was the mathematician?